# Converting CFG to Chomsky-Normal-Form?

Tags: formal-languages, automata, finite-automata

After removing $\epsilon$-productions and unit-productions of a grammar I obtain the following transformed CFG: 
 
  $S\rightarrow aAa|bBb|\epsilon|aa|bb$ 
  $A\rightarrow a$ 
  $B \rightarrow b$.

Now for a grammar to be in CNF it has to satisfy $S\rightarrow\epsilon$ if $\epsilon \in L(G)$, $A \rightarrow BC$ or $A \rightarrow a$.

Now using these rules I've transfored the grammar to:

$S \rightarrow CA|DB|\epsilon|AA|BB$ 
 
$A \rightarrow a$ 
$B \rightarrow b$ 
$C \rightarrow AA$ 
$D \rightarrow BB$

Now the question is, is this grammar in Chomsky-Normal-Form or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Seems to be correct.

Comment: which of the three allowable forms does $C\to aA$ match?

Comment: Ok fixed, now $C\rightarrow AA$ matches the form $A \rightarrow BC$ and so does D. Now it should be ok.